# A problem on Permutation/Combination.

Tags: permutations, combinations

**Q.How many ways no.s less than 10000 can be made with digits $1,2,3,0,4,5,6,7$?**

*My attempt*:

The no.s should be of $4$ digit.

It cant start with $0$

Then,the no.s of no.s possible should be $7*7*6*5=1470$ which doesnot match with the answer in the textbook.

Where is my mistake?

[Answer given in book is $4095$]

Comment: Does it mention how many digits the number should be?  (Are all numbers going to be four digits long or can some be three or two etc?)  Are the digits reusable or can they appear only once? (or is a number like $5535$ allowed?)

Comment: No other information is given.But your hint is eye opening.Thanks

Comment: Depending on the answers to those two questions I asked, the final total will change.  If there is no requirement on number of digits and no requirement on reusability of digits, then you can think of four positions and in each position you have eight choices for what digit appears.  We can then truncate the leading zeroes after the fact to make appearance more standard (I.e. $0023$ could be rewritten as $23$).  That would give an answer of 4096, very near your books answer of 4095.  Perhaps it stipulated *positive* numbers and so $0000$ doesn't count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of $8$ figures may be placed on each of $4$ places, which makes $8 \times 8 \times 8 \times 8 =4096$ possibilities. Take one for $0000$ which is $0$, so forbidden (as it starts with zero) and you have $4095$.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers can be one-or-two-or-three-or-four-digit.

So, there are $8+7\times7+7\times7\times6+7\times7\times6\times5=1821$ ways

Answer (score 0):

Remember, there are only 7 choices for the 1st digit as a # can't start with 0, and 8 choices for each subsequent digit

There can be 7 1-digit #s

There can be $7\times 8$ 2-digit #s

There can be $7\times 8^2$ 3 digit #s etc

so total #s = $7(1+8+8^2+8^3) = 4095$